# QDateEdit преобразовать в datetime Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, datetime

Имеется приложение с полем QDateEdit, где пользователь вводит дату, с другой стороны у меня есть функция, которая использует дату в формате datetime. Как QDateEdit можно преобразовать в datetime?

```
date = self.QDateEdit    #Получаю дату
datetime(date.dateTime())# Преобразую, но выдает ошибку
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\deriabin_ns\Preactor\Scheduler1.py", line 150, in copy_text
    print(datetime(date.dateTime()))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type QDateTime)
```

В функции использую дату в таком формате

```
datetime(2023, 3, 6, 8, 0, 0)
```

Comment: что выводит `print(date.dateTime)`?

Comment: print(date.dateTime)    --->    PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `QDateEdit` есть свойство `date` - это класс `QDate`, у которого есть много нужных в данном случае методов. Соответственно, в вашем случае можно написать так:

```py
date = self.QDateEdit  # Получаем дату
qdate_obj = date.date()  # Получаем объект `QDate`
my_datetime = datetime(qdate_obj.year(), qdate_obj.month(), qdate_obj.day())
```

Comment: Попробовал, но выдал такую ошибку     AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: Разобрался перед методом date нужны скобки date.date()